# SQL Permutations

Tags: sql, permutation

I have a data table that has the following information

```
ID | Value
1  | a
1  | b
1  | c
2  | a
2  | b
```

I need to build a target table that has all 2 level Permutations by ID

Result

```
ID | Value1 | Value 2
1  |   a    | b
1  |   a    | c
1  |   b    | a
1  |   b    | c
1  |   c    | a
1  |   c    | b
2  |   a    | b
2  |   b    | a
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You need to join your table with **itself** with conditions:

> id should be equal
>
> values should be different

Example

```
   select a.id, a.value value1, b.value value 2 
    from table a 
      join table b 
      on a.value!=b.value and a.id=b.id
```

Comment: cause you don't tell us table name )

Comment: Please explain your answer so that the question asker can understand how to apply it to the next problem they have.

Comment: @Wai Ha Lee, done. But... it's so simply query, that if user can't understand it - he may be not understand explanation.

Comment: Thank you. At least, with an explanation, they stand a better chance.